# How to navigate from parent project's page to a child project's page in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am working with xamarin forms and my solutions has 4 project in that one is commmon code and others for android, ios and uwp. Now when i run the solution using uwp emulator then it runs the first page of common code which is set in the common code app.xaml.cs but i want to set the start page from uwp project.Is there any way to set the start page in common code to a page which is present in the uwp project.

Comment: Hi, not too understanding, you can first explain his specific use of the scene. Maybe this document will be helpful .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is quite simple in your UWP application look for the App.xaml.cs class.

In that look for something like below:

```
if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)  
{  
   if (rootFrame.Content == null)  
  {  
    // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,  
    // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation  
    // parameter  
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);  
  }  
   // Ensure the current window is active  
   Window.Current.Activate();  
}
```

Here `rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);` is the piece of code which decides what page to load changing this to another page will do the trick

Good luck, Feel free to get back if you have queries

Answer (score 0):

Did you try in shared code this one?

```
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.WPF)
        {       
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new WpfStartPage());
        }
        else
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new StartPage());
        }
```

UWP update

```
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP)
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new WpfStartPage());
        }
        else
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new StartPage());
        }
```

Comment: WPF? I think he is talking about uwp!